# Getting Longitude and Latitude Values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

I am trying to connect to GPS from my code. I am doing so according [to this tutorial](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate = self;
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
 }

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    locLabel.text = [location description];
  }

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    locLabel.text = [error description];
  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  }
```

The above code is placed in a view controller called `GetMyLocationViewController`, and I have another view controller called `MainScreenViewController`.

When the screen loads, the `MainScreenViewController` gets loaded, and I will need the GPS location to continue operations with this screen.

In the `ViewDidLoad` method of `MainScreenViewController` I wrote the following;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GetMyLocationViewController *getMyLocationViewController = [[GetMyLocationViewController alloc]initwithXib:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:getMyLocationViewController Animation:YES];
    // AND THEN I NEED TO ACCESS THE LONGITUDE AND LATITUDE VALUES

 }
```

When the above code gets executed, the `viewDidLoad` method of `MainScreenViewController` gets executed, but not the `locationUpdate` method. The only way I could get the values of `longitude` and `latitude` is by the execution of `locationUpdate` method. So how can I get these values?

Answer (score 0):

Do you tested in a device? xcode before the version 4.2 dont have a GPS simulator, because of that the method locationUpdate never call.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)]) {  // Check if the class assigning itself as the delegate conforms to our protocol.  If not, the message will go nowhere.  Not good.
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you say that after `ViewDidLoad` , `locationUpdate` is called? and not exit after `ViewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: You need to implement the protocol that copy in te answer, this methods only going to update when GPS get a new coordinate.

Comment: what do you mean? i am a newbie :S can you please elaborate

Comment: Copy that to the implementation file

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are loading your `GetMyLocationViewController`? Your code only shows loading the `MainScreenViewController`, which, in its `-viewDidLoad` method, loads itself again, which would cause an infinite loop of loading and pushing `MainScreenViewControllers`.

UPDATE: That CoreLocationController class in the tutorial seems unnecessary. Rather that using it, make CLLocationManager a property of your GetMyLocationViewController. Make GetMyLocationViewController's -viewDidLoad method look like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     self.locationManager.delegate = self;
     [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

don't forget to import the CoreLocation library and implement the delegate methods.

Comment: oh, sorry i edited the code. I have typed the wrong bit of code (Look up for the modified code). Do you have any clue as in what i should do?